Chase around mechanical telephone exchange to trace call
I'm told there's a scene in an old (probably pre-1970s) film involving chasing around an old (maybe Stowger) exchange, physically pegging the switches while a phone call is in progress. This has to be completed before the caller hangs up so that his location can be determined. Can anybody identify the film?

Thanks to wqw for the useful example. I was asking because I was hoping to use a clip for educational purposes - none of my students have even heard of a Strowger switch - and although I don't believe it was the one I had in mind it is useful (to me at least). For this reason, I am really unable to edit the question to provide more relevant information. Sorry.
